# Remove columns from heatmap.2 figure?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, heatmap

Is it possible to remove sample columns within a heatmap that are not of interest without reanalyzing my data? For example, I plotted the following

[image: heatmap]

Using heatmap.2 to visualize the top 30 differentially expressed genes between 'IL2.OKT3' and 'IL2'. The heatmap displays the expression pattern across all samples and donors, however, I would only like to display the sample columns labeled 'IL2' and 'IL2.OKT3'. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of is to subset the data matrix you used to plot the heatmap. If your matrix is called `m` and you want to get rid of columns 15-20, replace `heatmap.2(m,....)` with

```
heatmap.2(m[, -(15:20)], .... )
```

And the columns will not be plotted.